# Data on trade - annual imports and exports country to country

Tags: trade, worldbank, oecd

I'm looking for a dataset of import and export trade (goods and services) between all combination of nations globally, by year, i.e.:
2015
Afghanistan > Albania (import $XXX, export $YYY)
Afghanistan > Algeria (import $XXX, export $YYY)
...
Zambia > Zimbabwe (import $XXX, $YYY)
2014
...

MIT's OEC (http://atlas.media.mit.edu/en/resources/about/) has a vast dataset, but at a product level, which I'm worried might not aggregate correctly to sources that are more authoritative (and seems an unfair use of their API as I'd need to get all their data). 
I've had a look through OECD and World Bank but haven't managed to identify in more granularity than 'Country > World (import $XXX, export $YYY)'.

Answer (score 3):

It might take quite a few queries, but all trade data should be available here: https://comtrade.un.org/data/

You can select up to 5 countries (either as reporter or as partner) to view their trade with all other countries (select `all` in the other box). So in about 50 queries you should be done. There's also a bulk download option which I haven't tried.